# Get all workspaces from Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to get all repositories from bitbucket API. The desired result is the same informatation as the "Your work" tab shows in the web. I have tried to use the `/repositories` and the `/workspaces` endopoints but I only get the information of the repositories I own. I want to get also other repositories (from other workspaces) which I have been invited and I have write access.

**EDIT:** if I query by the desired workspace, I get all repositories but I want to create a general solution for cases you don't know the workspace name.

Comment: Im facing same issue. I noticed that there is an api to get all workspace the user has access to using /2.0/user/permissions/workspaces/?q=permission="member". But it looks like the api is broken and always returns ownership permission

Comment: I have also tried this but same results as the default.